# input[type=submit] CSS is not working in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: css

The below code is not working in Internet Explorer 6. I can't put `class` or `id` in it. Are there any CSS hacks for that?

This code is in [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress). I can't modify the code; I can only modify the CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            form input[type=submit]{
                background-color:#FE9900;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                border:1px solid #000066;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <FORM action="">
            <INPUT type=text name=s> 
            <INPUT type=submit value=Search>
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes – IE6, being completely outdated, can't do this. What's your question?

Comment: Why can't you put a class in the input-tag? Is the tag automatically created or so?

Comment: I wpuld suggest that you got your own domain, and hosted your WordPress solution on that. Then you have access to all of the code, and you would be able to insert a class on the input-tag.

Is your current solution hosted on wordpress.org? Or your own domain?

Answer (score 11):

Instead, give the input a class, and then style it from there. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="myClass" value="Search" />
```

And then style the .myClass in your CSS. This should also work in IE6.

Comment: Yeah I don't get it either. How should I know that you couldn't insert some extra code?

Answer (score 5):

You're right, it doesn't work.

Quirksmode.org is an excellent site with browser compatibility info:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 3):

The Internet Explorer 6 doesn’t support the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors) `[attr="value"]`. So there is no way to address that submit input element with CSS only (IE 6 doesn’t support the [adjacence selector `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) and [`:last-of-type` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo) neither that would help in this case).

So the only options you have is to either make that element uniquely addressable by adding a class or ID or wrapping it into an additional `span` element.

Or – as you’ve already stated that you can’t do that – use JavaScript to select that element and apply the CSS rule to it. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can make this fairly easy:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").css({
    "background-color": "#FE9900",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "font-family": "Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
    "border": "1px solid #000066"
});
```